# Counting if name appears under a given date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataframe with a few columns, I will focus on the ones relevant to my issue.

I would like to return the value 1 for cases where a user's name appears in a row associated with a given date.

So here is an example:

```
user_name          date
    a            20/1/2019 
    a            20/1/2019
    c            21/1/2019
    c            21/1/2019
    a            21/1/2019
    b            20/1/2019
```

Using this as an example, this would be my desired output

```
user_name          date            val
    a            20/1/2019          1
    b            20/1/2019          1
    c            20/1/2019          0
    a            21/1/2019          1
    b            21/1/2019          0
    c            21/1/2019          1
```

I had though about use a case statement of sorts with the pseudo logic if name doesn't appear under a specific date then return 0 else return 1

```
case when user_name not in date then 0 else 1 end
```

but this doesn't seem to make sense

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if a name appears in a given date then return 1. So for example user_name a appears in 20 and 21...therefore we return the value 1 for both dates

Answer (score 0):

You may use a calendar table approach here.  In the absence of any formal tables containing all dates and users, we can use subqueries in their place:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.user_name,
    d.date,
    CASE WHEN t.user_name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS val
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_name FROM yourTable) u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM yourTable) d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.user_name = u.user_name AND
       t.date = d.date
ORDER BY
    d.date,
    u.user_name;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: . . The original data has duplicates, so this will return duplicate name/date combinations.

Comment: @Gordon How you are able to see such things without testing the code is completely beyond me ^ ^

Comment: The duplicates informed my solution.  It is why I didn't answer with a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `cross join` to generate rows and then logic to set the flag:

```
select u.user_name, d.date,
       (case when exists (select 1 from t where t.user_name = u.user_name and t.date = d.date)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from (select distinct user_name from t) u cross join
     (select distinct date from t) d ;
```